# LinkedIn not picking image specified by og:image

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

DEMO URL - http://maz.node1357.speedyrails.net/webreader/803

The page has open graph tags where the open graph image is served though HTTP from S3 is of 240px width and 320px height.

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://maz.node1357.speedyrails.net/webreader/803">
  <meta property="og:title" content="sharetest_4">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="MAZ">
  <meta property="og:description" content="test pdf 10 page">
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.amazonaws.com/maz_staging2/staging2env1/issues/00022/webreader/thumbs/staging2env1_00022_thumb_0001@2x.gif" />
```

Why does the Image Preview switcher appear here ? The first image seems to be the one specified by the `og:image` tag, but the second image never seems to load although there are many images in the page which are of bigger sizes than the ones specified by Linkedin.

I checked some other websites. Linkedin Sharing from this post on Techcrunch shows no switcher - [CLICK HERE](http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/25/apple-details-official-fix-for-ios-8-0-1-woes-will-release-ios-8-0-2-in-the-next-few-days/)

But sharing from this one does - [CLICK HERE](http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/23/watch-apples-first-timberlake-and-fallon-iphone-6-ads/)

Both of these URL have images of width=680px and height > 300px. Any guidelines on how the image fetching from open graph tags on Linkedin work ?

Comment: any answers? having same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Per the [LinkedIn Developer Reference](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin), you need the [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) namespace in the `html` tag.

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
   …
</body>
</html>
```